# How can i make one clustered index on two columns in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-indexes

I have this table

```
UserProgrammingLanguagesId
UserId,
Name,
ProgrammingLanguageId,
KnowledgeId.
```

I am inserting into ProgrammingLanguageId and KnowledgeId values that are FK-PK relationship.But i dont want,for example if one user has
ProgrammingLanguageId - 1(Java Script) and his knowledgde is KnowledgeId - 2
(Intermediate),to have same values after in that table.I want to make when some user has 1 with 2 values,to prevent repeating because one user can knows one programmign language with one knowledge id,not with two and reverse.

Here is uploadaed screenshot with the tables
https://ibb.co/sPn5zT7

```
//i am preventing this and it is working
insert into userPLs values(5,'9d313e61-8fb7-4011-88f0-6494621f43f7','Doe',1,1)

//How can i prevent this insert here?
insert into userPLs values(5,'9d313e61-8fb7-4011-88f0-6494621f43f7','Doe',1,2)
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/sPn5zT7 here are the tables Sir

Comment: In short: you want users to only be able to specify _one_ knowledge level per programming language? You need a unique constraint on `UserId, ProgrammingLanguageId`. In this case, `KnowledgeId` is irrelevant as its an attribute

Comment: I don't see why `Doe,2,1` would be invalid, (someone can be a beginner in many languages) but if it is, just create a unique constraint on `UserId,KnowledgeId` as well.

Comment: One employee should not have basic and intermediate in one language,how can i do that ?

Comment: Please update your question to reflect that then. Given the table structure, your requirement translates to "each user may only specify one language", which translates to a unique constraint on `UserId, ProgrammingLanguageId` like I already said

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to this, depending on the database.

One is to force the ordering on the two values and then have a unique constraint:

```
alter table userPLs add constraint chk_userPLS_ids
    check (ProgrammingLanguageId < KnowledgeId);

alter table userPLs add constraint unq_userPLS_ids
    unique (ProgrammingLanguageId, KnowledgeId);
```

This will only allow you to *insert* (1, 2), not (2, 1), so you cannot get duplicates.

The second method is to use `least()`/`greatest()` or similar logic for a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_userPLS_ids on
    userPLs ( least(ProgrammingLanguageId, KnowledgeId),
             greatest(ProgrammingLanguageId, KnowledgeId),
           );
```

Not all databases support `least()` and `greatest()`, but they are common functions in most databases.  Some databases don't support function-based indexes, but there is often a work-around.

In SQL Server, you need to use a computed column and `case` expressions:

alter table userPLs add column least_pkid as
    (case when ProgrammingLanguageId < KnowledgeId
          then ProgrammingLanguageId else KnowledgeId
     end) persisted;

alter table userPLs add column greatest_pkid as
    (case when ProgrammingLanguageId > KnowledgeId
          then ProgrammingLanguageId else KnowledgeId
     end) persisted;

```
create unique index unq_userPLS_ids on
    userPLs ( least_pk, greatest_pk );
```

I should add that you can also define a trigger for this purpose, but that is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gordon.i try thiscreate unique index unq_userPLS_ids on
 create unique index unq_userPLS_ids on
    userPLs (least(ProgrammingLanguageId, KnowledgeId)
             greatest(ProgrammingLanguageId, KnowledgeId)
           ) incorrect syntax near , but i deleted the all , except inside the methods.Btw i am using MS SQL